# Array salvando dados no banco com um campo escrito array

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, array, magento, model

Eu tenho dos campos dois quais salvo no banco de dados (no caso seria como comentário do pedido no magento, mas isso não importa muito). Esses campos estão sendo salvos corretamente, porém com um problema, ele salva um dos campos escritos `array`. Os campos de ponto de referência e tipo de endereços são salvos corretamente.

**Código HTML dos campos:**

```
<div class="field small small-left left">
  <label for="comments"><?php echo $this->__('Referência: ') ?></label>
  <div class="input-box">
      <input style="width: 100% !important;" class="input-text" id="comments_1" name="comments[]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Pontos de Referência') ?>" />
   </div>
</div>

   <div class="field info">
    <label for="commentsEnd" class="tipoEnd">Tipo de Endereço:</label>
    <div class="input-box">
       <div class="styled-select">
       <select id="comments_2" name="comments[]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Tipo de Endereço') ?>" class="onestep">
          <option value="">Selecione</option>
          <option value="residencial">Residencial</option>
          <option value="comercial">Comercial</option>
       </select>
       </div>
    </div>
```

**Código no Model do módulo, que percorre o `Array` e salva os campos:**

```
if (!empty($oscOrderData['comments'])) {

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    /* @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order */

    // Force array type
    if(!is_array($oscOrderData['comments']))
        $oscOrderData['comments'] = array($oscOrderData['comments']);

    foreach($oscOrderData['comments'] as $comment) {
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment);
    }
    $order->save();
}
```

Comment: Qual campo está salvando errado?

Comment: @ThiagoBarcala O que está acontecendo é que ele está salvando um campo a mais. Os dois campos são salvos corretamente, porém, ele salva um campo a mais escrito `array`.

Comment: Pode ser que tenha algum outro input no form com esse mesmo nome (comments[]) e tem valor "array". Verifique no navegador quais os valores enviados ao submeter o form. Se vc usa Chrome, aperte F12, clique na aba network, e submite o form. Vc vai poder ver o request e todos os valores enviados ao servidor.

Comment: Você pode procurar por comment[] na aba elements para ver se tem mais inputs do que deveria.

Comment: Qual é a estrutura do banco de dados e como está ficando esse registro errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema não estava em ter mais de um `input` com o `name="comments[]"`, mas estava na duplicação do código no arquivo Observer.php do módulo, ou seja, existiam dois códigos iguais e por isso estava salvando um campo a mais escrito `Array`. Retirei um dos códigos e o problema foi solucionado.